# C# variable attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, annotations

I am developing a web application with ASP.NET MVC.
I need to authorize users in two different ways now, so I had to adjust some thing in my Controllers.

One of the things was to change the annotation of the Controller from 
`[Authorize]` to `[AllowAnonymous]`.
The reason why I need two different ways to authorize my users, is because some of the users will use a different kind of authorization.

What is the best solution for this?
I would like to have some kind of config file that I will lookup, before the start.

Comment: `[AllowAnonymous]` will not check authorization

Comment: I think you may need to create an action filter that should get executed before your action. That means, create an action filter where perform the logic of all authorization, and decorate your action with that filter attribute. That is one way to achieve it.

Comment: the Annotation 'AllowAnonymous' is just used in that context

Comment: So there is no way to make the annotation itself variable?

Comment: No, because you have to hard-code it. Just like you can't vary any other code. All you can do is write code which produces variable _behaviour_

Comment: "some of the users will use a differnt kind of authorization" is far too vague. You may be able to do what you need purely through config or you might be needing to write filters or other code - it's impossible to say with the info provided. Are you possibly confusing authentication with authorisation, btw?

Comment: AuthorizeAttribute docs have some detail on authorising different users/roles, also allowing anonymous etc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Create a action filter and try to implement your authorization logic(two different kind of authorization).